# No route found for all my routes even though they show up in debug:router

Tags: php, routes, symfony

**Background:**

I am trying to learn Symfony3 and was playing around with Internationalization.

**Issue:**

I broke something and I can't get my routes to work again. The only route that is working is localhost:8000/ (homepage)

**What I have at the moment:**

config.yml

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }
    - { resource: "@CarBundle/Resources/config/services.yml" }

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: en

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    translator:      { fallbacks: [en] }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    #serializer:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#handler-id
        handler_id:  session.handler.native_file
        save_path:   "%kernel.root_dir%/../var/sessions/%kernel.environment%"
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true
    assets: ~
    php_errors:
        log: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
    form_themes:
        - 'bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig'

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/../var/data/data.sqlite"
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }
```

routing.yml

```
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
car:
    resource: "@CarBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
```

Example controller (for login)

```
<?php

/**
 * Handles login operations
 */

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use function dump;

class SecurityController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="login")
     */
    public function loginAction(Request $request)
    {
        // here we are getting a service from the container        
        $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', array(
           'last_username' => $lastUsername,           
            'error'        => $error, 

        ));
    }
}
```

All my routes

[image]

Just to be clear: I have tried `bin/console cache:clear` and many different configuration options... to no avail...

**EDIT 1: The profiler has the following message:**

```
Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /login/" (from "http://localhost:8000/register")" at C:\xampp\htdocs\php\frameworks\symfony\autotrader\var\cache\dev\classes.php line 3487
```

**EDIT 2: New error after removing `use function dump;`**

```
Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /login/" (from "http://localhost:8000/")" at C:\xampp\htdocs\php\frameworks\symfony\autotrader\var\cache\dev\classes.php line 3487
```

Comment: You get 404 ? Did you checked the profiler ?

Comment: I have Edited the OP with the message, huh, it says `from "http://localhost:8000/register"`... why would `/register` have anything to do with this? `/register` also seems to be the only route that works...

Comment: What is this: `use function dump;` ? try to remove it.

Comment: I have no idea, I think netbeans could have generated it... never put that in there by hand. Just refreshing my cache because it still doesn't work.

Comment: Yep, clearing my cache doesn't change anything... so I made a test route and just returned a string response and it works... so there is something wrong specifically with my login method route that is broken...

Comment: Okay, here's something funny... the login route works perfectly if I add a leading slash... `@Route("/login/")`, I have no clue what could be causing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not set /login/ route but only /login route - without last slash in your routes.